# Try to connect locally to Chatbot but get unauthorized error

Tags: botframework, chatbot, ngrok

I loaded the EchoBot template from Microsoft here:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4

I started a new project and try to run it locally.  No MicrosoftAppID or MicrosoftAppPassword is provided.

[image]

Then I loaded the latest Bot Framework Emulator v4.7

I connect locally, again no App ID or App Password:

[image]

However when I try to send a message I get unauthorized error, why would I get unauthorized error when connecting locally?

[image]

The server is definitely running locally and the local URL is correct:

[image]

One question I want to ask is the login dependent on any 3rd party URL call?  My company security policy is blocking all URL unless whitelisted, so if this is the case, maybe the authentication is blocked?  What would be the URL for me to whitelist?

EDIT:  I tried it a VM outside of the company network and it works!  So something must be getting blocked.  Any idea?

Comment: I recall having an issue like this a few months ago, but in the end I just used the appid/apppassword I think. To my recollection, trying to integrate ngrok and the emulator might have been part of the problem, and I see you're doing that, where ngrok is not required at all if you're trying to run locally. Try remove it in emulator settings.

Comment: Hi Hilton, I tried to remove ngrok, the result seem to be the same, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by using a VM outside the company network instead.  It's not a solution, but it is a work around.  I highly suspect some port are being blocked by company firewall but not sure what so I am not sure how to get it whitelisted.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your emulator settings? I tried using the same template and it works just fine for me. Your issue seems to be similar to this already reported GitHub issue https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1837

Comment: Well I don't think there is anything wrong with the emulator, I think it's something wrong with the firewall/domain blocker at work so I don't think it will help.

Comment: The Emulator is trying to post the activity to your bot, which is then sending the Unauthorized response back to the Emulator. When you are behind a corporate network or a proxy, it does block some port resulting in such errors. You can make use of [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and go through the trace to narrow down on the issue.

Comment: But it's on the local box though, it shouldn't go anywhere except locally?  Anyway it's alright, I ended up using the VM.